# Solving the most profit algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I am practicing algorithms for upcoming job interviews and I am having trouble correctly implementing this one. I am trying to also maximize efficiency as well. Here is the problem:

Maximize the profit of your business selling metal rods. If you sell N metal rods of length L, you receive N * L * metal_price. The remaining smaller metal rods will be trashed. To cut metal rods, you need to pay cost_per_cut for every cut. What is the max profit you can make?

```
constraints:
lengths will be 1 to 50 elements, inclusive.
each element of length will lie in range [1,10000]
1 <= metal_price, cost_per_cut <=1000
```

sample input:

```
cost_per_cut =1

metal_price =10

lengths = [26,103, 59]

return: 1770
```

how the book solved this is that the most optimal length of rod is 6. so we cut 4 pieces of length 6 from 1st rod, and throw piece of length 2 from it. next we cut 17 pieces of length 6 from 2nd rod, and throw away piece of length 1. for the third, we cut 9 pieces of length 6, and throw a piece of length 5. so in total we have made 30 cuts. therefore, 30*6*10 - 30*1 - 1770

Here is my attempt so far:

```
def  maxProfit( cost_per_cut,  metal_price,  lengths):

     profit =0
     for num in lengths:
```

I'm just not really sure how to go about doing this. Should I iterate over the numbers and see what the lowest number they're divisible by and use that? Any ideas?

Comment: Just curious, ultimately do we have to make sure that there is one optimal length of rods being sold? Like in this case for all the elements, it is 6? Or are we just concerned about maximising the profit? Because then we can sell rods of different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Since the input ranges are quite small, can you not just brute force this

```
    static int getProfit(int[] rods, int cutCost, int metalPrice, int L)
    {
        int profit = 0;
        foreach (int rod in rods)
        {
            if (rod % L == 0)
            {
                profit += (metalPrice * rod - (rod / L - 1) * cutCost);
            }
            else
            {
                profit += (metalPrice * (rod - rod % L) - (rod / L) * cutCost);
            }
        }
        return profit;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] rods = new int[] { 26,103,59};
        int cutCost =1;
        int metalPrice=10;
        int maxProfit = 0;
        for (int L = 1; L <= 10000; ++L)
        {
            int profit= getProfit(rods, cutCost, metalPrice, L);
            if (profit > maxProfit)
            {
                maxProfit = profit;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(maxProfit);
    }
```

Comment: this is wrong solution, in the foreach loop, you need to check if the profit for each length is bigger than 0. there are chances the cut is very expensive, you dont want to cut for certain lengths.

Answer (score 1):

While the algorithm provided by @JasonL, suitably answers the question, but I think just because the length of elements lie in the range [1,1000] we don't have to necessarily start from 1 and go all the way to 1000.

Take your case for example:

```
lengths = [26,103, 59]
```

The ideal situation would be if the **smallest** of these numbers i.e. 26 is a factor of 103 and 59 as well. We won't have to trash any length and have maximum profit.

So in your algorithm that's the first check you should do. Now if the smallest number doesn't divide the other two numbers. Just loop through the largest number till 1. As @user3386109, rightly pointed out, it's not necessary that the smallest one is always included, however the largest one *should* be since we are maximising profit here.

So in your case, instead of checking from [1,1000] if you just check from [1,103] and find the largest multiples of these numbers less than or equal to 26,103, 59 and calculate the profits appropriately. You should have the maximum profit.

Time complexity of this algorithm -> **`O(max(lengths)*size(lengths))`** where `lengths` is the array `[26,103, 59]` and `max()` is the largest element of that array and `size()` represents the length of that array.

Hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: This assumes that the shortest rod will be used, but that's not always the case. For example, given lengths [3, 59, 104], the maximum profit is at length 8. Which means that the shortest rod is not used at all.  Of course, you can limit your search range to the length of the longest rod.

Comment: @user3386109, that makes sense! I'll update my answer to reflect the same.