# how to find maximum profit while selling some garbage item

Tags: algorithm

I have one problem statement for which i need write an algo. can somebody help me?

Problem is :

i have different length of iron rod let say {26, 103, 59}, i want to sell the same length of iron rod so that i can earn maximum profit. Also i have to cutting charge lets say 10 Rs/unit.

Case 1, if cutting charge is Rs 100 and sell length of 51 feet with cost 100 per unit.

```
then 103/ 51 = 2 length ((51 * 100 * 2)  - ((1  * 100) + 200 )  = 9900
     59 / 51 = 1 length ((51 * 100 * 1) - ((8 * 100) + 1* 100)   = 4200
     26/52 =  0 length((0 * 100)) - (26 * 100 ) = -2600

now total profit is  = 11500
```

But if cutting charge is vary then this calculation like failed, can some one tell how can develop algo to find the maximum profit.

Comment: This sounds like homework. The point is that you sit down with a piece of paper and come up with a solution yourself. If we just tell you how to solve it, you won't learn anything.

Comment: you are right but i made lot of efforts but failed, need just some hint to start the thing .

Comment: Your primary problem is that your problem is not clearly defined and well explained. If you can represent the problem clearly you will probably find it easier to solve. 

It seems you are somewhat struggling with the English language as well... perhaps try to draw a few pictures on a piece of paper to help you understand things visually..

Comment: This might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030757/solving-the-most-profit-algorithm